# Read Manufacturer data BLE device react-native-ble-plx

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I need to work with BLE integration using React-native.

I am using this package: https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/

I have successfully searched a BLE device now I need to read it's manufacturer data and check for some values

issue: I am getting manufacturer data in string (Base64) format and I converted into byte array with following code.

```
convertStringToByteArray(str) {
        String.prototype.encodeHex = function () {
            var bytes = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
                bytes.push(this.charCodeAt(i));
            }
            return bytes;
        };
    
        var byteArray = str.encodeHex();
        return byteArray
    }
```

which results as below.

```
[xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx]
```

I am not sure how to go with it.

in Native iOS i get output in DATA format which is given by Apple itself. not sure how to handle in this

**Requirement**
**I need to convert that subrange 2..<3 to Uint8 and check if Uint8 result contains some integeor**

can anyone help me how I can parse such data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution string was base64 ENCODED I have to decode string first then convert to byte array

Answer (score 2):

Using buffer js library, it can be achieved using the following snippet:

```
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer


const strval = "base-64-encoded-string";
const buffer = new Buffer(strval, 'base64');
const bufStr = buffer.toString('hex'); //make sure to encode it as 'hex' and not 'string'
```